# html2convas not capturing images, version 4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas for capture a screenshot of particular div, it works fine but not caprturing the images in that div

My Script code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
     html2canvas(element, {
       logging: true,
       allowTaint: true,
       onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
         }

    });
});
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
// Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/,"data:application/octet-stream");
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "design.png").attr("href", newData);
});
```

Here is the link of live problem tht i am facing, check that by click on preview button appearing on the page scroll down a little bit
https://www.citystatebeads.com/pages/example-page

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [README](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/readme.md) on `html2canvas`:

> It doesn't magically circumvent any browser content policy restrictions either, so rendering cross-origin content will require a [proxy](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Proxies) to get the content to the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Since your image is located on `https://cdn.shopify.com` and your origin is `https://www.citystatebeads.com`, it's not going to render the image.

Comment: Please wait i am going to change the image path in specific folder, let me try once